# How to store a floating point number as text without losing precision?

Tags: python, floating-point

Like the question says. Converting to / from the (truncated) string representations can affect their precision. But storing them in other formats like pickle makes them unreadable (yes, I want this too).

How can I store floating point numbers in text without losing precision?

Comment: Have you tested the string conversions to be sure that the conversion is going to be a problem for you?

Comment: What precision are you looking for?

Comment: For readability without information loss, `repr` is by far your best bet.  It's guaranteed by the language that `float(repr(x))` recovers `x` without loss of information.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, please give me a citing too, as there are contrary answers. I am using Python 2.7 itself.

Comment: Well, it's not the best reference, but it's mentioned in the floating-point chapter of the tutorial:  http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: It's also discussed extensively in the proposal to change the floating-point repr for Python 3 (and later for Python 2.7): http://bugs.python.org/issue1580

Comment: Great... Please add all these into an answer, it deserves to be **the** answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using the builtin function `repr()`. From the documentation:

> repr(object) -> string
>
> Return the canonical string representation of the object.
>   For most object types, eval(repr(object)) == object.

Comment: The problem is the "most". `float` doesn't always fall under that.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, out of curiosity, can you give examples for that?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, unfortunately.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:  In Python 2.7 and Python >= 3.1, `eval(repr(x)) == x` will work just fine for all finite floats.  More generally, `float(repr(x))` will recover `x` for any float `x`, including infinities and nans.  If there are counter-examples, they're bugs, and should be reported as such.

Answer (score 8):

Store it in binary or a power thereof.

```
>>> (3.4).hex()
'0x1.b333333333333p+1'

>>> float.fromhex('0x1.b333333333333p+1')
3.4
```

Comment: important would be if the result of this is equal to the start, so somethink like `check = lambda a: float.fromhex(a.hex())  == a` and with this, test several values. But in general, your approach is very fine.

Comment: @glglgl: That operation should be perfectly idempotent for every non-infinite, non-NaN IEEE 754 double precision float.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: And for infinities, too!  (And NaNs, provided you don't care about potentially losing sign and/or payload bits, or turning signaling NaNs into quiet NaNs.)

Comment: This is the canonical correct answer.  It's worth noting that this format supported by the C standard library (and therefore by many other languages, since they tend to leverage it).

Answer (score -1):

`pickle.dumps` will do it, but I believe `float(str(floatval)) == floatval` too -- at least on the same system...

Comment: No;  on Python <= 2.7 and Python 3.1, `str()` of a float will lose precision (though for Python 3.2 and later, it doesn't).  You want to use `repr` instead.