# Is json.dumps guaranteed not to lose floating point precision?

Tags: python

I am talking of a JSON conversion like:

```
>>> a = {'asas': 1/7.0}
>>> b = json.dumps(a)
>>> c = json.loads(b)
>>> c
{u'asas': 0.14285714285714285}
>>> c['asas'] == 1.0/7
True
```

Is the JSON encoding guaranteed not to roundoff the number?

In my [How to store a floating point number as text without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113767/how-to-store-a-floating-point-number-as-text-without-losing-precision#comment14562791_11113767),  Mark Dickinson says that `repr` doesnt cause loss of precision. Does `json.dumps` use the `repr`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no mention of `repr` anywhere in the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) docs, but it is the current implementation of float-to-string coercion:

```
FLOAT_REPR = repr
```

([`Lib/json/encoder.py`, line 31](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c4b8c8064ef4/Lib/json/encoder.py#l31))

You can build your own [`JSONEncoder`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) if you want a strict guarantee.